# why does uboot invalidate TLB s, icache, BP array at beginning

Tags: arm, tlb, u-boot

On arm platform, the u-boot will invalidate TLBs, icache and BP array at beginning, but what's the reason? Is it necessary?

```
cpu_init_crit:
/*
 * Invalidate L1 I/D
 */
mov r0, #0          @ set up for MCR
mcr p15, 0, r0, c8, c7, 0   @ invalidate TLBs
mcr p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 0   @ invalidate icache
mcr p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 6   @ invalidate BP array
mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c10, 4  @ DSB
mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 4   @ ISB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reset may be hard or soft.  It is possible for something to jump to a reset vector.  If cache is enabled with stale entries, the code may crash resulting in a system not booting.  This can be more common than you think as SDRAM may miss behave after a cold power on and mis-read causing a crash.  Often a watchdog or unrecoverable faults will jump to the reset vector.  Finally, there maybe *u-boot* systems in XIP NOR flash.  Some systems/code may just jump to this code to perform a soft reset.

In all of these cases, the *debug* available is *NIL*.  You may have a working system in 99.9999% of the cases.  Having to trouble shoot a boot failure on particular hardware which only occurs in a hot bar or an ice cream freezer might make you enjoy this extra code.  Ie, there are rare circumstances where it is needed.

Hardware failures are much more common as supply rails come on line.  Datasheets describe properly behaving systems with power/temperature, etc in range.  *u-boot* may not operate in this ideal world.  If your concern is boot time, you are much better to write your own loader (keep this code though) or optimize things like BSS clearing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On A15/A7/A12 you do not need to do cache/mmu/btb invalidation on post-reset, so this is done just for "paranoia" reasons. However, there might be cores which do not perform auto-invalidate on reset so this code just makes sure that the same behavior is preserved across different core types.

Answer (score 0):

This is necessary in the cases where the invalidation is not done in hardware on a reset (cold or warm). Another more practical reason is that U-Boot is typically not the first piece of code that runs on the hardware. In most cases there would be the ROM code that runs before U-Boot and to avoid making any assumptions regarding the state of the hardware when U-Boot got control of the system it's safer to always try and get the hardware to a known state and proceed from there.